# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBody()')

Tags: javascript, text, textarea, gettext, ckeditor4.x

---

### CKEditor Ver.4
This is a cshtml file.

I try to get two kind of content types (with html tags & without one).
But it seems not work that.

Error Msg: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBody')`

- HTML code:

```html
<textarea class="edit-normal" id="content" msg="content" disabled="disabled">@Html.Raw(Model.Data.Content)</textarea>
```

- JS code

```js
function GetData() {
    // TODO: Get content with html tags ✓
    var contentEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('content');
    var content = contentEditor.getData();

    // TODO: Get content without html tags
    var rawContent = contentEditor.document.getBody().getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to have a fallback if the getBody() is undefined.
Some cases can be solved by using a questionMark(?) before the param you're trying to show.

Possibly add the || {} at the end of the rawContent snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to set a fallback . But I still need try to get  a plain text.

Comment: That's great, how can I do ? thanks.

Comment: var rawContent = contentEditor.document.getBody().getText() || "Fallback Text"; 

or, just do var rawContent = contentEditor.document.getBody().getText() || {};

else i dont have any more ideas :)

Comment: muchas gracias!